# what does fopen return?

Tags: php, file-io

In the following statement :

```
$handle = fopen('./readme.txt');
```

what variable is `$handle` ? Is it a boolean or what ?

I am in a doubt after running these 2 different statements :

```
if($handle) echo "File opened !"
else echo "Error opening the file !";
```

and

```
$line = fgets($handle);
```

So what variable is actually `$handle` ?

Comment: It's the file handler. It represents the file when you want to access it. Examples would be fwrite, fread, etc.

Comment: Actually it returns pointer to the file with which you are working .... http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fopen.asp

Comment: It's a [resource type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/resource.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns either a `resource` or `boolean` false. Resources are known as a *special type* and are explained in detail [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

Answer (score 3):

Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php